# How would I print coordinates from my 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

How would I print coordinates from my 2d array? I have to print the coordinates from wherever the number 5 is. The numbers are randomly generated into the array using `Math.random`. Here is the code:

```java
public class MultiArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] array = new int[3][4];

        for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[index].length; j++) {
                array[index][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            }
        }

        for (int column = 0; column < array[0].length; column++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
                System.out.print(array[row][column] + " | ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

```java
for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
        if (array[row][col] == 5) {
            System.out.println("Row: " + row + " Col: " + col + " has value 5");
        }
    }
}
```

It treats first row / col as 0 (starting from 0)

Comment: wow, thanks! Now that I look at it, it isn't hard. I'm just learning 2d arrays

Comment: If my answer satisfies your question, please mark it as accepted so the question is resolved.

Comment: well it works but the row and columns are reversed when printed

Comment: I just switched row and col in the System.out and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like Java, not JavaScript (just noting that based on the tags on the question). They are very different things, so just being clear.

I'm also not clear on what you mean by "when the number is 5." Do you mean when the second value of the multidimensional array is 5?

There's kind of a bunch of confusion in your second outer for loop if that's the case. You would want to iterate all values of `array` (so `array.length`), and then all inner values of those values.

To output the value of the array when the inner (right-hand) values of the array are 5, you would need a condition where your `System.out` call is made.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) for this purpose:

```java
int m = 3;
int n = 4;
// random array (n * m)
int[][] arr1 = IntStream.range(0, n)
        .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, m)
                // generate random array
                .map(j -> (int) (Math.random() * 10))
                .toArray())
        .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

```java
int x = 5;
// finding (x) coordinates
int[][] arr2 = IntStream.range(0, arr1.length)
        .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, arr1[i].length)
                .filter(j -> arr1[i][j] == x)
                // (x) coordinates
                .mapToObj(j -> new int[]{i, j})
                .toArray(int[][]::new))
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

```java
// output
Arrays.stream(arr1).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
Arrays.stream(arr2).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
[3, 0, 5]
[8, 6, 1]
[4, 7, 1]
[5, 0, 3]
```

```
[0, 2]
[3, 0]
```